# How to access user's fpath as opposed to system's fpath with a script?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

test.zsh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh                                                                                                           

for f in ${fpath}; do
    echo ${f}
done
```

outputs:

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Calendar
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/AIX
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/BSD
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Base
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Cygwin
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Darwin
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Debian
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Linux
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Mandriva
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Redhat
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Solaris
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Exceptions
/usr/share/zsh/functions/MIME
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Newuser
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts
/usr/share/zsh/functions/TCP
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info/Backends
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zftp
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle
```

While the command line output has a few extra entries:

```
╭─ting@core ~/code/autojump  ‹install-zsh-local*›
╰─➤  echo $fpath       
/home/ting/code/oh-my-zsh/plugins/git
/home/ting/code/oh-my-zsh/functions
/home/ting/code/oh-my-zsh/completions
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Calendar
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/AIX
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/BSD
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Base
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Cygwin
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Darwin
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Debian
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Linux
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Mandriva
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Redhat
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Solaris
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Zsh
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Exceptions
/usr/share/zsh/functions/MIME
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Newuser
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts
/usr/share/zsh/functions/TCP
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info/Backends
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zftp
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle
```

How can I get the script to access the user's fpath as opposed to the system's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this, because the user's `fpath` isn't set by a simple assignment in a key-value configuration file, it's set by a potentially complex script. For example, my `fpath` differs depending on the version of zsh and what directories exist on the system. You can source the user's `~/.zshrc`, but that may do all kinds of other things (and in particular may not work if zsh is not running in a terminal, and may print things and otherwise assume the shell is an interactive one).

All instances of zsh source `~/.zshenv`, so suggest to the user that they set their `fpath` from there.